# Issue while displaying mutliple images as a results in Ubuntu + Python 2.7.6

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am getting below given error, while displaying multiple images as result:

init done 
opengl support available 
pci id for fd 28: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo

Please help.....have upgraded and updated my ubuntu 14.04 OS.

Regards,
Rahul